# How to create real dynamic input forms in angular?

Tags: jquery, angular, frontend, abstraction, micro-frontend

I have few forms to create/update resources(for example employee resource) which vary slightly based on selected type. Please suggest which of the below option I should consider?

**1. Separate components:**

For each type adds duplication/extra effort and requires code changes after few initial releases for new forms

**2.Reusable component:**

I tried reusable component however its getting complicated to manage different fields based on type and the form has few input fields which require user selection based on some search text and populate dropdown based on API call.
For example selecting an employee based on few characters of employee and perform API lookup based on search text.

Utilize the formArray, formGroup to create separate forms and create separate components for distinct input fields and reuse those.
Create a configuration which maps type to corresponding input fields and some metadata like required, searchable, selectable etc.

**3. Generic component with extracted forms and logic:**

In this option angular creates form container and based on selected type specific form file is pulled from external storage. This file has jQuery function which updates form container created by angular and add actual form contents like html (input field, select options, checkboxes etc.), styles (for each html element), actions (API calls based on type of field).
So any new form addition requires only creating new jQuery file in external storage.
This option achieve abstraction/ inversion of control up to some extent.

---

*From domain perspective angular application is creating/updating resources of different application which does not have UI or very poor UI from third party which is difficult to replace completely.
So the forms are belonging to external application.*

*My preference is 2--> 1 --> 3*

Comment: For Me second option is good as your requirement is.

Comment: [formly](https://formly.dev/) may be of interest to you.

Comment: Does formly support REST api lookup for specific search text on options input? @BizzyBob

Answer (score 0):

*First Thought:*

I would differentiate between the abstraction levels:

- Form-Component
- View-Component

I would try to create **reusable** form components. They can handle specific API calls - if necessary, or a reusable `<address-component>`.

Then I would use **separate** components for the different use-cases / views.

Having one big View-Component that is responsible for different use-cases can quickly turn into a mess IMO.

---

*Second Thought:*

If you already know that there will be 100s of different views in the future, I would try to go for the fully dynamic solution with [ngx-formly](https://formly.dev/guide/custom-formly-field) and custom templates.

---

*Third Thought:*

I always like to quote the awesome [Sandi Metz](https://sandimetz.com/blog/2016/1/20/the-wrong-abstraction), in such cases:

> Duplication is far cheaper than the wrong abstraction

So if you are not sure, I would start with duplication, because over time you will recognize (based on the duplication) which use-cases can be abstracted and which not.